# Cold Fusion 11: Variable is Undefined in session

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Recently some users have been experiencing this error. This error doesn't appear until the user is in the application for a bit (Ranged from a couple minutes to hour and a half).

When this issue first came up, I modified the application.cfm file which contains the timeout variables. This helped one user, but now more are experiencing the same error. Below is the modified code, I exended the timeout to 200 minutes.

```
<CFAPPLICATION 
  NAME="MyApplication"
  SESSIONMANAGEMENT="Yes"
  sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,200,0)#"
  applicationtimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,200,0)#">
```

My question: Users are still experiencing this timeout error within 5 minutes, after I set the timeout to 200 minutes. Can there be a variable or something that is set on the CF Admin side which overrides my timeout span? If there is not, I will need to research into this more. Any suggestions or comments are helpful, thanks.

Comment: There are a couple settings you may want to check. http://i.imgur.com/ivaf0lO.png

Comment: @TRose I am guessing that is the CF Admin interface. Am I correct? I do not have access to the Admin section, so I have to ask the admins to check their side. That is why I want to make sure that there is a timeout section that they manage before sending an email out.

Comment: So it was working correctly at some point, but recently stopped? Were any changes made to the code (updates applied, etcetera) before this started happening? There is a [maximum timeout setting](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html) setting in the CF Admin: *".... Specify a maximum session time-out. Application code cannot set a time-out greater than this value. The default value for this time-out is two days.*

Comment: @Chris yes, that's the CF Admin interface. If no code was changed before the error started occuring, one can only assume some setting was changed serverside.

Comment: @Leigh I believe it was working correctly at some point, we just took over the project and users started reporting the issue the past couple of weeks. Other than increasing the timeout span, there were no changes to the code that dealt with the session state/variables.  The one thing is that we changed the web server that hosted the application.

Comment: @TRose Described the changes above, and I agree with you.  I will contact the CF Administrators to see what their settings are,  Thanks.

Comment: If you have a `structClear("session")` or something like that anywhere in your application, then it might execute when you least expect it, like when the user opens another browser tab.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I just got more information. The request timeout is 60 seconds. Session timeouts default to 20 minutes.  @DanBracuk I found a line of code in the file where most people have encountered the error: 
<cfsetting requesttimeout="?">   I do not think this will affect the session timeout, but just the request timeout after reading about it here https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfsetting.html  Would you be able to confirm my conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need more info from the hosting provider. Common issues include:

1. They are load balancing and not using sticky sessions. So the user will have to login and create a session on each server that is part of the loadbalanced cluster.
2. They have a proxy or webserver in front of the ColdFusion server with configuration that alters the response from the ColdFusion server.
3. They have settings in the CFAdmin console that limit the application settings, as per the comments provided by TRose and Chris.

Answer (score 0):

**So the concern is timing out:** IIS, Apache, and TomCat web services can timeout as well. For example if Apache is set to timeout in 300 seconds but Coldfusion is set to timeout in 350 the web service will always trigger beforehand (it won't matter what you do in Coldfusion Admin or Cfsettings because the web server supersedes it).

So web server timeout implementations could front run your Coldfusion to timeouts.